# How to inject parameter in Jubula or RCP Testing Tool?

Tags: java, rcp, gui-testing, jubula, eclipse-rcptt

I want to test my RCP application with GUI tests. I've found two possible tools: Jubula and RCP Testing Tool.

Does anybody know, how to inject parameters into the tests, so that I can use one test case with multiple inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way for the RCP Testing Tool: https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/faq/pass-value/

1. Add the parameter you want to include in your test to the aut vm arguments like `-DpropertyName=propertyValue`
2. Use the ECP function `get-java-property "propertyName"` to get the value of the passed property

Comment: Yeah, thanks @RyanHaining. I've completed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add parameters to [parameter contexts](https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/contexts/parameters/), unite it to [super context](https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/contexts/super/), add context to test case and then use it as $parametername in test case script.

In RCPTT if a test case refers to more that one supercontext, then all possible combinations of tuples from these supercontexts will be used.

There are good examples in the mentioned documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Data Set feature. It's basically a table with each row meaning a separate cycle of the same Test Case repeated.

The columns of the table are named after the parameters of the Test Cases.

You can also use Excel files (.xls) as Data Set source.